# Combining almost identical rows into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a tricky problem that I wouldn't mind a bit of help on, I've made some progress using queries that I've here and elsewhere, but am getting seriously stumped now.

I have a mailing list that has numerous near duplications that I'm trying to combine into one meaningful row, taking data such as this.

```
Title Forename Surname  Address1      Postcode Phone    Age   Income    Ownership   Gas

Mrs   D         Andrews 122 Somewhere BH10     123456   66-70           Homeowner 
Ms    Diane     Andrews 122 Somewhere BH10     123456         £25-40                EDF
```

and making one row along the lines of

```
Title Forename Surname  Address1      Postcode Phone    Age   Income    Ownership   Gas

Mrs   Diane     Andrews 122 Somewhere BH10     123456   66-70 £25-40    Homeowner   EDF
```

I have over 127 million records, most duplicated with a similar pattern, but no clear logic as was proven when I added an identity field. I also have over 90 columns to consider, so it's a bit of work!
There isn't a clear pattern to the data, so I'm thinking I may have a huge **case** statement to try to climb over.

Using the following code I can get a decent start on only returning the full name, but with the pattern of data - trying to compare the fields across rows is as follows.

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM
    Mailing c1
    JOIN
    Mailingc2 ON c1.Telephone1 = c2.Telephone1 AND c1.surname = c2.surname
WHERE
    len(c1.Forename) > len(c2.Forename)
AND c2.over_18  <> '' 
AND c1.Telephone1 = '123456'
```

Has anyone got any pointers as to how I should progress please? I'm open to discussion and ideas...

I'm using SQL 2005 and apologies in advance if the tagging is all over the place!

Cheers,

Jon

Comment: . . There is a reason why third-party vendors and software exist to do householding and name matching.  If you have a database with 120 million rows, then your company should invest in a real solution to this problem.  SQL is not an adequate solution.

Comment: Hi Gordon - I work for a data warehouse, we're looking to develop those type of solutions in-house. We do have external sources, but this is also proving to be a valuable learning process for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work by assuming that all persons with the same surname and phone number (Do all persons have a phone?) were the same person?

```
INSERT INTO newtable <fieldnames>
SELECT lastname,phone,max(field3),max(field4)....
FROM oldtable
GROUP BY lastname,phone
```

But that would collapse John Smith and Jack Smith living together into one person.

Perhaps you should consider outsourcing it to a data-entry sweatshop somewhere, adter you have preprocessed the data. :-)

And/or be prepared to take the flack for mistaken bundling.

Perhaps adding something like "To improve our green footprint, we have merged x listings on your adress together. If you would like separate mailings, please contact us"

Comment: Thanks Leif - (I'm also joining on the first line of the Address)

We use the phone number almost as a unique identifier - the plan is that only one contact per address will be migrated from the holding table and probably use it as the PK.

I think, considering the quality of the data there will be a considerable drop in the number of clean records returned. I'll take the flak, but I want to minimise the pain.